# Mysql search text in one column

Tags: mysql, search, text

For Example our table;

İd--------Price---------Level
1 ------100-300 ------ 1,2
2 ---------200----------1
3 ------100-280--------1,3

We want search a price value is 110. 110 is between  100-300  and 100-280 so id 1 and id 2 must listed. Can we write this query with my-sql?.

Additional , we want search price and level value. Price 110 and level 2 searching. Can we write this query with my-sql?.

Thank You

Comment: why is the price range saved like that, why not just a min and max column? and to answer your question: yes you can.

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that database tables should be created with the idea that it will satisfy your query needs. It doesn't make sense to have a table with a price "100-300" which represents a String (or in mysql a VARCHAR) and you want to treat this as a number. So what to do?

1) The first thing i would do is re write my table schema having a minPrice and maxPrice fields, so this way you could have this:

```
İd----minPrice---maxPrice------level
1 ------100---------300 ------ 1,2
2 ------200---------200----------1
3 ------100---------280--------1,3
```

2) Then your query would be like:

```
SELECT id FROM Mytable x WHERE myValue >=  x.minPrice AND myValue <= x.maxPrice
```

3) In case you also want to look for a level value. you would do:

```
SELECT id FROM Mytable x WHERE myValue >=  x.minPrice AND myValue <= x.maxPrice AND myLevelValue IN (x.level)
```

Comment: x is sql variable? You said myLevelValue IN (x.level) but I this column have more value for example id 1 have level 1,2 (1 and 2 multiple data). For your tactics, I must divide my "level" field?. But this solution hard for me, I must modify that script without change database. Can you suggest me with sql command.

Comment: x is an alias of your table. When I say "IN (x.level)" it means it will iterate on your fields separated by comma, you dont have to split them by hand. It is ok that way. What you need to do is change the values of MyTable---> your table name, MyValue --> my price value.. MylevelValue ---> your level number in case you want to look for it.. You dont have to divide the level field

Answer (score 0):

Use two columns for the price ...

```
ID  FROM     TO  LEVEL
1    100    300  1,2
2    200    200  1
3    100    280  1,3
```

Then SQL:

```
SELECT `level` FROM `table`
WHERE X >= `from` AND X <= `to`
```